# Why are my bootstrap-styles not applied correctly?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I copied this form from the bootstrap page to my website.

```
<form>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

For some reason the bootstrap-style is not applied correctly. The button has a border-radius to the left.

[image: screenshot]

I added Bootstrap via npm, and I'm using that

> ../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

in the angular-cli.json

EDIT: I downloaded the *min.css* from the CDN, included that one and it works. This seems to be an issue with the npm-version. Maybe I am using the wrong file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have figured it out already, it is because of the Bootstrap version.  The markup you are using, is for beta 3 – and for the final Bootstrap 4 release. The final Bootstrap 4 was actually [released yesterday](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2018/01/18/bootstrap-4/).

**In detail:**
There were not many changes from Bootstrap 4 **beta 2** to **beta 3**, but the *Input group* component was actually rewritten, as it was stated in the [beta 3 release notes](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/12/28/bootstrap-4-beta-3/) at December 28, 2017.

In beta 2 the corresponding class was `.input-group-addon` and the markup as follows:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Placeholder">
    <button class="input-group-addon btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

In beta 3 `.input-group-addon` was replaced by `.input-group-{prepend|append}` and the markup changed this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Placeholder">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code as below

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this and it broke my navbar too without improving the inputs. When I moved the link-tag as an import-statement in my styles.css the same thing happened. 
I'm using Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2, is that creating the issue?

Comment: I checked this and on the ngBootstrap page it says it is tested with 4.0.0-beta.3